# How do I pass UTM parameters to an iframe?

Tags: iframe, parameters

I'd like to pass the parent page's utm_source, utm_medium and utm_campaign parameters to my iframe. (facebook page tab)

I do have access to the iframe's source, so I can change that. I can also edit the page in which it will be embedded.

Current iframe code:

```
<iframe src="MyPageURLisHere" width="810" height="850"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I can do some basic html and some very (very..) basic PHP, so it would be awesome if you could explain it to me like you would explain it to a newbie :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve, but I'm assuming you are receiving the utm_source, utm_medium and utm_campaign via GET variables.

To work with them inside PHP you would do the following:

```
$utm_source = $_GET['utm_source'];
$utm_medium = $_GET['utm_medium'];
$utm_campaign = $_GET['utm_campaign'];
```

If you would like to know what is going here exactly I recommend starting here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

To fully achieve what I think you want you need to insert the created variables in the iframe URL:

```
<iframe src="pageurl.php?utm_source=<?php echo $utm_source; ?>&utm_medium=<?php echo $utm_medium; ?>&utm_campaign=<?php echo $utm_campaign; ?>" width="810" height="850"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

You're not taking security measures here, but this code should get the basics to work.

Good luck and let me know if you have any additional questions!